# React+Vite problema con formulario y modificacion de productos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

estoy realizando un proyecto donde tengo que realizar un formulario para poder crear y modificar productos, el tema es que al hacer clic para editar este carga los datos en el formulario pero en los select no aparece la informacion correspondiente al producto para modificar y no sé si se debe a como está escrito el codigo de los selects o ya depende de otra cosa o como se están manejando los datos. Pido disculpas si no lo pasé correctamente o la consulta no es adecuada, necesito sugerencias de como poder reolver ese problema, gracias.

**Componente principal Productos**

```
const Productos = () => {
  const [mostrarFormulario, setMostrarFormulario] = useState(false);
  const [datosProducto, setDatosProducto] = useState({});
  const showSelects = true;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios
    .get( baseUrl + "/productos/all?cantidad=500&pagina=1")
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data.data);
      console.log(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error al obtener los rubros:", error);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log("Estado de datosProducto:", datosProducto);

  const toggleFormulario = (data) => {
    console.log("Previo a la actualización - prev:", mostrarFormulario);
    console.log("Previo a la actualización - data:", data);
    setMostrarFormulario((prev) => !prev);
    setDatosProducto(data);
  

  const handleEditProduct = (producto) => {
    axios
      .get(baseUrl + "/productos/getById?id=" + producto.id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        toggleFormulario(response.data.data);
        // Establecer el estado del producto seleccionado para la edición
        setSelectedRow(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener los rubros:", error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <div className='main__container'>

        <button onClick={toggleFormulario} className='btn-frm'>Crear Producto</button>

        {mostrarFormulario && (
          <div className={`formulario-container ${mostrarFormulario ? 'visible' :''}`}>
            <Formulario
              pageType="productos"
              toggleFormulario={toggleFormulario}
              showSelects={showSelects}
              datosProducto={datosProducto}
            />
          </div>
        )}

        <CombinedTable columns={ProductColumns} data={data} onEditClick{handleEditProduct}/>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Productos;
```

**Componente del formulario:**

```
const Formulario = ({ pageType, toggleFormulario, showSelects, datosProducto }) => {
  const [modoEdicion, setModoEdicion] = useState(false);
  
  const [nroRep, setNroRep] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.nro_rep : "");
  const [desRep, setDesRep] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.des_rep : "");
  const [costo, setCosto] = useState("");
  const [idInterno, setIdInterno] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.id : "");
  const [fabricacionPropia, setFabricacionPropia] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.fabricacion_propia : false);
  const [habilitado, setHabilitado] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.habilitado : false);
  const [porcentajeIva, setPorcentajeIva] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.porcentaje_iva : "");
  const [otroGravamen, setOtroGravamen] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.otro_gravamen : "");
  const [subRubro, setSubRubro] = useState([]);
  const [subRubroElegido, setSubRubroElegido] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.sub_rubro : "");
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.categoria || "" : "");
  const [categorias, setCategorias] = useState([]);
  const [rubro, setRubro] = useState([]);
  const [rubroPerteneciente, setRubroPerteneciente] = useState("");
  const [temporada, setTemporada] = useState(datosProducto ? datosProducto.temporada : "");
  const [temporadas, setTemporadas] = useState([]);
  const [talles, setTalles] = useState(datosProducto && datosProducto.talles ? datosProducto.talles : []);
  const [nuevoCategoria, setNuevoCategoria] = useState("");
  const [nuevoTemporada, setNuevoTemporada] = useState("");
  const [nuevoSubRubro, setNuevoSubRubro] = useState("");
  const [nuevoTalle, setNuevoTalle] = useState("");
  const [costoUnitario, setCostoUnitario] = useState("");


  const [agregarCurvaIncremental, setAgregarCurvaIncremental] = useState(false);
  const [nuevoTalleIncremental, setNuevoTalleIncremental] = useState("");
  const [nuevoMargenVenta, setNuevoMargenVenta] = useState("");
  const [nuevoTalleIncrementalInicial, setnuevoTalleIncrementalInicial] = useState("");
  const [nuevoBarcode, setNuevoBarcode] = useState("");

  const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";

  useEffect(() => {
    // Realizar la petición a la API para obtener los rubros
    axios
      .get(baseUrl + "/rubros/all?cantidad=5&pagina=1")
      .then((response) => {
        setRubro(response.data.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener los rubros:", error);
      });

    // Realizar la petición a la API para obtener los subrubros
    axios
      .get(baseUrl + "/subRubros/all?cantidad=10&pagina=1")
      .then((response) => {
        setSubRubro(response.data.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener los subrubros:", error);
      });

    axios
      .get(baseUrl + "/categorias/all?cantidad=10&pagina=1")
      .then((response) => {
        setCategorias(response.data.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener las categorias:", error);
      });

    axios
      .get(baseUrl + "/temporadas/all?cantidad=10&pagina=1")
      .then((response) => {
        setTemporadas(response.data.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener las temporadas:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (modoEdicion && datosProducto) {
      // Actualizar el estado 'categoria' con el valor de la categoría del producto
      setCategoria(datosProducto.categoria);
    }
  }, [modoEdicion, datosProducto]);


  // Estados adicionales para controlar la visibilidad del input de texto
  const [mostrarInputCategoria, setMostrarInputCategoria] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarInputTemporada, setMostrarInputTemporada] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarInputSubRubro, setMostrarInputSubRubro] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarInputTalles, setMostrarInputTalles] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarRecuadroLateral, setMostrarRecuadroLateral] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarRubroPerteneciente, setMostrarRubroPerteneciente] = useState(false);
  const [mostrarNombreSubRubro, setMostrarNombreSubRubro] = useState(false);

  const fieldSetters = {
    nro_rep: setNroRep,
    des_rep: setDesRep,
    costo: setCosto,
    id_interno: setIdInterno,
    fabricacion_propia: setFabricacionPropia,
    habilitado: setHabilitado,
    porcentaje_iva: setPorcentajeIva,
    otro_gravamen: setOtroGravamen,
    subRubro: setSubRubro,
    sub_rubro: setSubRubroElegido,
    categoria: setCategoria,
    rubroPerteneciente: setRubroPerteneciente,
    temporada: setTemporada,
    talles: setTalles,
    nuevoCategoria: setNuevoCategoria,
    nuevoTemporada: setNuevoTemporada,
    nuevoSubRubro: setNuevoSubRubro,
    nuevoTalle: setNuevoTalle,
    costoUnitario: setCostoUnitario,
  };

  function resetStateValues() {
    setNroRep(null);
    setDesRep(null);
    setCosto(null);
    setIdInterno(null);
    setFabricacionPropia(null);
    setHabilitado(null);
    setPorcentajeIva(null);
    setOtroGravamen(null);
    setSubRubroElegido(null);
    setCategoria(null);
    setRubroPerteneciente(null);
    setTemporada(null);
    setNuevoCategoria(null);
    setNuevoTemporada(null);
    setNuevoSubRubro(null);
    setNuevoTalle(null);
    setCostoUnitario(null);
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;

    // Actualiza el estado correspondiente
    const setFunction = fieldSetters[name];
    if (setFunction) {
      console.log(
        `Changing ${name} to: ${type === "checkbox" ? checked : value}`
      );
      setFunction(type === "checkbox" ? checked : value);
    }
  };

  const handleCrearClick = (campo) => {
    // Mostrar el input de texto correspondiente al hacer clic en "Crear"
    if (campo === "categoria") {
      setMostrarInputCategoria(true);
    } else if (campo === "temporada") {
      setMostrarInputTemporada(true);
    } else if (campo === "sub_rubro") {
      setMostrarInputSubRubro(true);
      setMostrarRecuadroLateral(true);
      setMostrarRubroPerteneciente(true);
      setMostrarNombreSubRubro(true);
    } else if (campo === "talles") {
      setMostrarInputTalles(true);
    }
  };

  const handleGuardarClick = (campo) => {
    // Guardar el valor ingresado y ocultar el input de texto
    if (campo === "categoria") {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categorias/crear", {
          des_cat: nuevoCategoria,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.categoria);
          setCategorias([...categorias, response.data.categoria]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error al crear una categoria:", error);
        });

      setNuevoCategoria("");
      setMostrarInputCategoria(false);
    } else if (campo === "temporada") {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/temporadas/crear", {
          des_tem: nuevoTemporada,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.temporada);
          setTemporadas([...temporadas, response.data.temporada]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error al crear una temporada:", error);
        });
      setNuevoTemporada("");
      setMostrarInputTemporada(false);
    } else if (campo === "sub_rubro") {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/subRubros/crear", {
          des_cla: nuevoSubRubro,
          id_rubros: rubroPerteneciente,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data.data);
          setSubRubro([...subRubro, response.data.subRubro]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error al obtener los rubros:", error);
        });
      setMostrarRubroPerteneciente(false);
      setMostrarNombreSubRubro(false);
      setMostrarInputSubRubro(false);
      setMostrarRecuadroLateral(false);
    } else if (campo === "talles") {
      setTalles([...talles, { talle: nuevoTalle, costo_unit: costoUnitario }]);
      setNuevoTalle("");
      setCostoUnitario("");
      setMostrarInputTalles(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productos/crear", {
        nro_rep: nroRep,
        des_rep: desRep,
        nro_cla: subRubroElegido,
        fabricacion_propia: fabricacionPropia,
        habilitado: habilitado,
        nro_pro: null,
        id_interno: idInterno,
        porcentaje_iva: porcentajeIva,
        otro_gravamen: otroGravamen,
        nro_tem: temporada,
        nro_cat: categoria,
        talles: talles,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        resetStateValues();
        toggleFormulario();
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: "¡Exito!",
          text: "El producto fue creado con exito...",
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al crear un producto:", error);
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "¡Ups..!",
          text: "El producto no fue creado, al parecer faltan campos o se repiten algunos...",
        });
      });
  };

  const visibleSections = {
    productos: [
      "nro_rep",
      "des_rep",
      "id_interno",
      "fabricacion_propia",
      "habilitado",
      "porcentaje_iva",
      "otro_gravamen",
      "sub_rubro",
      "categoria",
      "temporada",
      "talles",
      "crear_prod",
    ],
    categorias: ["categoria"],
    temporadas: ["temporada"],
    subRubros: ["sub_rubro"],
    talles: ["talles"],
  };

  const visibleFields = visibleSections[pageType] || [];

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="cnt-form">
      <div className="form-prod">
        <div className="grupo-forms">
          {visibleFields.includes("nro_rep") && (
            <div className="group">
              <label>NUMERO PRODUCTO:</label>
              <input
                placeholder="numero producto"
                type="text"
                name="nro_rep"
                value={nroRep}
                onChange={handleChange}
                id="nro_prod"
              />
            </div>
          )}


          {visibleFields.includes("sub_rubro") && (
            <div
              className="group"
              style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
            >
              {showSelects && (
                <div>
                  <label>SUB RUBRO:</label>
                  <select name="sub_rubro" onChange={handleChange} value={subRubroElegido}>
                    <option value="-1">--Seleccione una--</option>
                    {subRubro.length > 0 ? (
                      subRubro.map((opcion) => (
                        <option key={opcion.nro_cla} value={opcion.nro_cla}>
                          {opcion.des_cla}
                        </option>
                      ))
                    ) : (
                      <option value="">No hay opciones disponibles</option>
                    )}
                  </select>
                </div>
              )}
              {mostrarInputSubRubro && (
                <div className="recuadro-lateral">
                  {mostrarRubroPerteneciente && (
                    <div className="group">
                      <label>RUBRO PERTENECIENTE:</label>
                      <select name="rubroPerteneciente" onChange={handleChange}>
                        <option value="-1">--Seleccione una--</option>
                        {/* opciones para rubroPerteneciente */}
                        {rubro.map((opcion) => (
                          <option key={opcion.nro_tip} value={opcion.nro_tip}>
                            {opcion.des_tip}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {mostrarNombreSubRubro && (
                    <div className="group">
                      <label>NOMBRE DEL SUB-RUBRO:</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="nuevoSubRubro"
                        value={nuevoSubRubro}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => handleGuardarClick("sub_rubro")}
                    className="btn-crear"
                  >
                    Guardar
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
              {!mostrarInputSubRubro && (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => handleCrearClick("sub_rubro")}
                  className="btn-crear"
                >
                  Agregar
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          )}

{visibleFields.includes("categoria") && (
  <div className="group" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
    {showSelects && (
      <div>
        <label>CATEGORIA:</label>
        <select
          name="categoria"
          value={categoria || ""}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option value="-1">-- Seleccione una--</option>
          {/* Opciones para categoria */}
          {Array.isArray(categorias) &&
            categorias.map((opcion) => (
              <option key={opcion.nro_cat} value={opcion.nro_cat}>
                {opcion.des_cat}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    )}

    {/* Mostrar el input de texto para agregar una nueva categoría */}
    {mostrarInputCategoria ? (
      <div className="recuadro-lateral">
        <h3>Crear Categoria</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="nuevoCategoria"
          value={nuevoCategoria}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="nombre de la categoria..."
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleGuardarClick("categoria")}
          className="btn-crear"
        >
          Guardar
        </button>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => handleCrearClick("categoria")}
        className="btn-crear"
      >
        Agregar
      </button>
    )}
  </div>
)}
        </div>

        <div className="grupo-forms">
          {visibleFields.includes("temporada") && (
            <div
              className="group"
              style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
            >
              {showSelects && (
                <div>
                  <label>TEMPORADA:</label>
                  <select
                    name="temporada"
                    value={temporada}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <option value="-1">-- Seleccione una --</option>
                    {Array.isArray(temporadas) &&
                      temporadas.map((opcion) => (
                        <option key={opcion.nro_tem} value={opcion.nro_tem}>
                          {opcion.des_tem}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                  </select>
                </div>
              )}
              {mostrarInputTemporada ? (
                <div className="recuadro-lateral">
                  <h3>Crear Temporada</h3>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="nuevoTemporada"
                    value={nuevoTemporada}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => handleGuardarClick("temporada")}
                    className="btn-crear"
                  >
                    Guardar
                  </button>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => handleCrearClick("temporada")}
                  className="btn-crear"
                >
                  Agregar
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          )}


                {/* Botón adicional con el id "ocultarBtn" */}
                <button
                  id="ocultarBtn"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => handleGuardarClick("talles")}
                  className="btn-crear"
                >
                  Agregar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {visibleFields.includes("crear_prod") && (
        <input
          className="btn-submit-form"
          type="submit"
          value={"Crear"}
          style={{ fontWeight: 800 }}
        />
      )}
    </form>
  );
};
export default Formulario;
```

**Componente de la tabla:**

```
const TableBody = ({ page, prepareRow, onEditClick, setSelectedRow }) => (
  <tbody>
    {page.map((row) => {
      prepareRow(row);
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map((cell) => (
            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
          ))}
          <td>
            <button onClick={() => onEditClick(row.original)}>Editar</button>
            <button onClick={() => setSelectedRow(row.original)}>Detalle</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
);

const CombinedTable = ({ columns, data, onEditClick }) => {
  console.log('Received Columns:', columns);
  console.log('Received Data:', data);
  const memoColumns = useMemo(() => (Array.isArray(columns) ? columns : []), [columns]);
  const memoData = useMemo(() => (Array.isArray(data) ? data : []), [data]);

  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter,
    page,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    canNextPage,
    canPreviousPage,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns: memoColumns,
      data: memoData,
    },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    usePagination
  );

  const { globalFilter } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredData(page);
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalFilter filter={globalFilter} setFilter={setGlobalFilter} />
      {globalFilter && (
        <table {...getTableProps()} className="table">
          <TableHeader headerGroups={headerGroups} />
          <TableBody page={filteredData} prepareRow={prepareRow} onEditClick={onEditClick} setSelectedRow={setSelectedRow} />
        </table>
      )}
      <PaginationButtons
        previousPage={previousPage}
        nextPage={nextPage}
        canPreviousPage={canPreviousPage}
        canNextPage={canNextPage}
      />
 
    </>
  );
};
export default CombinedTable;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vamos por partes.. vite para vos porque tiene que ver en tu problema? parece demasiado codigo como para que lo podamos entender, donde esta ahi el combo que tiene problemas y la parte de lo llenas???

Answer (score 0):

En los `<select/>` que estás utilizando no estás controlando el valor que toman. Es importante que utilices la property `value` con el valor de un estado. Al actualizar este estado, se actualizará el select. Es importante que este valor coincida con el `value` de alguna de las opciones que contiene. Te doy un ejemplo:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("opcion1");

const handleChange = (e) => {
   const newValue = e.target.value;
   setValue(newValue)
}

return <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value="opcion1">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">opcion 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">opcion 3</option>
</select>
```

Recuerda aplicar el manejo del `value` y `onChange` de todos tus selects. Si desearías establecer el valor del select luego de traer los datos desde una API, simplemente llamas a la función `setValue` con el valor deseado como argumento. Recuerda, que dentro del `<select/>` debe haber un `<option/>` cuyo value sea el mismo al que recibió el select.

Comment: perdon la demora, pero ahi no lo estarias aplicando de manera diferente? ya que vos estableces las opciones y yo en mi codigo estoy utilizando "map" para armar el array con las opciones ya que son traidas del back

Comment: Era solo a modo de ejemplo. Vos tenés que hacer el map con las opciones adentro del select, pero el value y el onchange tenés que manejarlos como hice yo.